# Cross compile from Windows to Linux using os/exec Command

Tags: go, build

The title mostly says it. I know that I can do

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
```

in cmd before I `go build`, but I'm trying to write a build script and do it all with exec.Command.

My `go build -o etc` works with exec.Command (it builds), but when printing out GOOS in a test script after either of this commands:

```
cmd := exec.Command("set", "GOOS=linux")
// OR
cmd := exec.Command("set GOOS=linux")
```

I get `windows`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Set the `Env` field of [exec.Cmd](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd). See also [os.Environ](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Environ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you just use a tool like [Gox](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox) instead. It cross-compiles into every supported build target by just executing `gox`. It also has options if you only want to build for certain targets.

As for the code you're asking about, `exec.Command` doesn't create a new process, or really do anything other than create a `Cmd` struct. The os/exec documentation (specifically the docs for the [Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) function) has an example of what you seem to be trying to do- execute another program with custom environment variable assignments... see the `Example (Environment)` section of the linked documentation and try to follow that structure if you still want to cross-compile your way.

Comment: So if I want to set GOOS and GOARCH, I go can do within the cmd.Env slice?

Comment: Doing that will invoke another command with those environment variables set. This only makes sense if the other command you're invoking is `go build`, which seems to be what you are trying to do...